# with open file - could not convert string to float: '-' - python

Tags: python

I am getting the following error from my code:

```
File "D:/beverages.py", line XX, in <module>
    relst.append(Residents(float(value[0]),float(value[1]),str(value[2])))
    ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'
```

The code is below:

```
import math

class Residents :
    def __init__(self,x,y,drink):
        self._xco = x
        self._yco = y
        self._drink = drink

    def drink(self):
       return self._drink

    def distance(self,other):
        z = math.sqrt((float(self._xco) - float(other._xco))**2 + (float(self._yco) - float(other._yco))**2)
        return z
    def close(self,other):
        if self.distance(other) < 1:
            return True
        return False

with open("surveydata.txt") as file :
    file1 = file.readline()
    relst = []
    for line in file1 :
        value = line.split()
        relst.append(Residents(float(value[0]),float(value[1]),str(value[2])))

x = input("Input a x-coordinate : ")
y = input("Input a y-coordinate : ")
defau = Residents(x,y,drink = "unknown")

sumcoke = 0
sumpepsi = 0
for res in relst :
    if res.close(defau):
        if res.drink() == "Coke" : 
            sumcoke += 1
        elif res.drink() == "Pepsi": 
            sumpepsi += 1
        pass

print("Number of Coke drinkers are : {0}". format(sumcoke) )
print("Number of Pepsi drinkers are : {0}". format(sumpepsi) )
```

The `surveydata.txt` file contains:

```
-3.043296714578294 -1.8118219429417417  Pepsi
-2.934406412013738 -3.2258867426312845  Pepsi
3.750989559940674 0.6649706751908528  Coke
4.453731061614226 1.1760692786505302  Coke
-3.3141673450571307 2.7471154522861942  Coke
-1.5611978286453065 0.9748847584776836  Coke
-0.6446977323819532 -1.4945077535804119  Pepsi
-4.280039869935868 3.2099331922984433  Coke
```

I cannot figure out why the error is complaining about a single `-` character, shouldn't it be processing the entire field (with sign *and* digits)?

Comment: Please only add the relevant code. Also, could you do a bit of debugging to find out which line exactly from your surveydata.txt is causing the error?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Perform the basic debugging: print out the offending values just before the point of failure.  Trace those back to earlier code to determine the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem lies here:

```
with open("surveydata.txt") as file:
    file1 = file.readline() # <-- read ONE line
    relst = []
    for line in file1 :
        value = line.split()
        relst.append(Residents(float(value[0]),float(value[1]),str(value[2])))
```

The `file1` variable contains only one line of the file (as a string) rather than every line (as an collection of strings). This means the `for line in file1` will iterate over each *character* in the string rather than each *line* in the collection, and that's why it's complaining about a single, solitary `-` character.

So you should change `file1 = file.readline()` to `file1 = file.readlines()` to read ALL lines:

```
with open("surveydata.txt") as file:
    file1 = file.readlines()
    relst = []
    for line in file1:
        value = line.split()
        relst.append(Residents(float(value[0]),float(value[1]),str(value[2])))
```

Also, especially for larger files, it is much more efficient to iterate over the file itself as opposed to using `.readlines()`, as you won't be loading the whole file into memory. Therefore, the final code should look like this:

```
with open("surveydata.txt") as file:
    relst = []
    for line in file:
        value = line.split()
        relst.append(Residents(float(value[0]),float(value[1]),str(value[2])))
```